# I need to extract each resourceList values and loop them in

Tags: regex, jmeter, performance-testing, json-extract

```
{"result":{"moreRows":0,"resourceList":[204030,201319,178141,201926,204013,178148,178173,178174,178175,178177,165789,178181,178186,178187,178188,178189,178190,178193,178207,178208,178209,178216,178219,178222,178223,178225,202682,201729,204031,204014,201848,202493,204010,204012,204011,202018,201815,204015,204032]}
```

I have tried using regex extractor `"resourceList":\[(.*?)]},"` but it is giving all values like :

```
204030,201319,178141,201926,204013,178148,178173,178174,178175,178177,165789,178181,178186,178187,178188,178189,178190,178193,178207,178208,178209,178216,178219,178222,178223,178225,202682,201729,204031,204014,201848,202493,204010,204012,204011,202018,201815,204015,204032
```

What im looking for is like as below:
resourceList_1=204030
resourceList_2=201319
.
.
.
.
.etc

Any help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) instead, for example:
[image]

"-1" means extract all results, they will be named as `resourceList_N` as per your requirement, and with `resourceList_matchNr` for the total number.